# how to install mysqldb in python3.4

Tags: python, mysql-python

```
import MySQLdb
```

Open database connection

```
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","password","TESTDB" )
```

Prepare a cursor object using cursor() method

```
cursor = db.cursor()
```

Execute SQL query using execute() method.

```
cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS EMPLOYEE")
```

Fetch a single row using `fetchone()` method.

Disconnect from server

```
db.close()
```

> ERROR: "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm
>   4.5.4\bin\runnerw.exe" C:\Python34\python.exe C:/Users/Ambuj/PycharmProjects/Demo/manage.py runserver 8000
>   Performing system checks...
>
> System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
>
> You have unapplied migrations; your app may not work properly until
>   they are applied. Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
>   October 24, 2015 - 00:14:49 Django version 1.8.5, using settings
>   'Demo.settings' Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
>   Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.

I cannot install mysqldb in Django.

Comment: Have you tried running python manage.py migrate

Comment: It is not recognizing this command in command prompt.It is showing error when running in python console

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have removed the jarring ultra bold comments.  They are not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to run the below code *in your command prompt* to fix this error:

```
    python manage.py migrate
```

This will help bring over unused apps into your app that are needed to allow your app run.

See the documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/.

Comment: It is not recognizing this command in command prompt.It is showing error when running in python console

Comment: Check your installed apps, and make sure you have all the new apps that you're working on in there.  It is found in your settings.py file.